# Creating a file object only works when I use an absolute path

Tags: java, java-io, intellij-14

I want to let the user input the file name, and be able to read through that file. I then get the error that the file is not found. The file is in the same module, and I want it to work without having to specify the absolute path.
I am using Intellij.

This is what I want, but I get a FileNotFoundException.

```
File dataFile = new File("lottacash.csv");
```

This is the way I got it to work.

```
File dataFile = new File("C:\\FolderWithModuels\\ModuelProject\\"+ "lottacash.csv");
```